# Why Background color bug in Google Chrome device mode appears?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive

When I change this page to device mode in Google chrome desktop version, There is a tiny line that shown in the bottom of header and it is unwanted.

[image]

Here is HTML code of header:

```
<header class="header">
  <img src="./assets/avatar.png" alt="avatar">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Samane Yaghoubi</h1>
    <h2 class="position">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>Frontend Developer
    </h2>
    <a class="button outline icon" href="https://github.com/SamaneYaghoobi" target="_blank">
      <i class="fa-brands fa-github"></i>My Github Profile
    </a>
  </div>
  <a class="button outline lang icon small" href="#" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i>Fa
  </a>
</header>
```

`header` has gray background color and `title div` has white background color

It seems that 1 pixel from `header` shown in the bottom of `title` element.

It's a strange bug I think.

The project address:
https://samaane.ir/css

The project source code:
https://github.com/SamaneYaghoobi/css

Comment: Do you mean "device mode"? Did you refresh after switching? You often need to rerender after switching.

Comment: I can't see your project or source code where I am, which is why you're expected to show your code in your question. Please add the relevant CSS in a demo snippet.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce this on Chrome Version 106.0.5249.119 (Official Build) (64-bit Windows).

Comment: @isherwood Yes I edited it thanks. I refresh after switching, I think there is a point that when the page already loaded in desktop mode and then switch to device mode, the line appears.

Comment: @isherwood The CSS code is too long and I think it probably would't help because the bug happened in the special scenario.

Comment: @Kitswas I test in 3 different devices and OS, it remains. Please wait until the page already loaded then switch to device mode.

Comment: Ok. Here's some additional info. That line appears and disappears while zooming in or out when in device mode on Edge or Chrome. It happens even after the page is refreshed in device mode.

Comment: Zooming in shows this line on Brave mobile too. I propose that the question be reworded since it probably not a bug but a CSS related doubt. Asking 'why' it happens might be better.